# Setear Hora minutos y segundos en DateTime de PHP

Tags: php, datetime

tengo el siguiente código para parsear fechas en PHP hacia un objeto tipo `DateTime`, solo me queda como setear horas, minutos, segundos a `0`

```php
$strTime = '01/09/2021';

$phpDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $strTime, new DateTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));

print_r( $phpDateTime );

$mysqlTime =  date_format($phpDateTime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $mysqlTime;
```

**Salida**

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2021-09-01 11:39:58.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Madrid
)
2021-09-01 11:39:58
```

Es decir que quiero que la hora este a 0 así:
`2021-09-01 00:00:00`

Comment: ¿Has probado con la función setTime? https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.settime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez creado el objeto DateTime puedes usar el método setTime para poner a 0 las horas, minutos y segundos

```
    $strTime = '01/09/2021';
    $phpDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $strTime, new 
 DateTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    print_r( $phpDateTime );
    $phpDateTime->setTime(0,0,0);
    $mysqlTime =  date_format($phpDateTime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $mysqlTime;
```